# Angularjs & PHP submitting, POST and GET

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, angularjs

I need help with this code.

When i click on one of this elements

```
<li ng-repeat="mesa in mesas" ng-click="select($index,mesa.table_number)">
  <div class="round1" ng-if="selectedIndex === $index">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="round" ng-if="selectedIndex !== $index">&nbsp;</div>
  MESA {{mesa.table_number}}</li>
```

The code of the angularjs post its value.

```
$scope.select = function (index, id){
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    $scope.options = true;
    $scope.idhttp = id;
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '../../php/getDetalles.php',
      data: {
        'mesa' : $scope.idhttp
      }
    }).then(function successCallback(data) {
        $scope.detalles = data
    }, function errorCallback(data) {
        alert('No Response');
    });
```

So then with the post of the element number i'm trying to get the result of this query.

PHP

```
<?php
include('base.php');
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$msfu = $request->mesa;
$data = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, price FROM orders WHERE table_number LIKE '$msfu'",$connect);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
};
echo json_encode($data);
mysql_close($connect);?>
```

THEN (MORE ANGULARJS)

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '../../php/getDetalles.php',
    }).then(function successCallback(data) {
        $scope.detalles = data,
        $scope.cuentas = data
    }, function errorCallback(data) {
        $scope.mesas = 'No Response';
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="pedidos_table">
  <div id="pedidos_table_item" ng-repeat="detalle in detalles">
    <p id="pedidos_table_item_name">{{detalle.name}}</p>
    <p id="pedidos_table_item_price">{{detalle.price}}$</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to post on `$scope.idhttp` the number `1`. But even if in the query I insert manually the value 1 the code keeps me duplicating the fields and printing nothing on them (empty fields). I'm going crazy on this can anybody help me?

Comment: Question: Why is your select query duplicating your SQL fields?

Comment: @lin i would love to know it...

Comment: Which part of your code is duplicating your fields? The query or your PHP logic or AngularJS logic / view?? Cant follow you right now. Could you explain why you are using `LIKE` this time?

Comment: @lin i think its the query the one that its duplicating the fields, i've just tried to put the php on the html file so it shows directly the result wothout angular and i have the same problem so there is an issue or in my db or in php on the query or the code. This is what i used:

Comment: <div id="pedidos_table">
   <?php
    include('../../php/base.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE table_number = '1'",$connect);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   ?>
   <div id="pedidos_table_item" ng-repeat="detalle in detalles">
       <p id="pedidos_table_item_name"><!-- {{detalle.name}} --><?php echo $row['name'];?></p>
        <p id="pedidos_table_item_price"><!-- {{detalle.price}} --><?php echo $row['price'];}?>$</p>
   </div>
 </div>

Comment: Ok, now making the php code directly on the HTML. It works fine without the ng-repeat that was duplicating the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.then` method of an $http promise resolves with a `response` object, not `data`.

```
$scope.select = function (index, id){
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    $scope.options = true;
    $scope.idhttp = id;
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '../../php/getDetalles.php',
      data: {
        'mesa' : $scope.idhttp
      }
    //}).then(function successCallback(data) {
    }).then (function onSuccess(response)
        //DATA is property of response object
        var data = response.data;
        $scope.detalles = data
    }, function errorCallback(data) {
        alert('No Response');
    });
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)

Comment: OK, now is showing the correct quantity of elements, but there's still no print of the elements on the code html

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i added an [] on the php code after $data = $row. So it ends like these.
PHP

```
<?php
include('base.php');
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$msfu = $request->mesa;
$data = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, price FROM orders WHERE table_number = '$msfu'",$connect);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
};
echo json_encode($data);
mysql_close($connect);?>
```

ANGULARJS

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '../../php/getDetalles.php',
      data: {
        'mesa' : $scope.idhttp
      }
    }).then (function onSuccess(response){
        var data = response.data;
        $scope.detalles = data
    }, function errorCallback(data) {
        alert('No Response');
    });

$http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '../../php/getDetalles.php'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.detalles = response.data,
            $scope.cuentas = response.data
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.entradas = 'No Response';
        });
```

THANKS TO ALL

@lin and @georgeawg.